# Dependent multi-select Element

Tags: html, mootools

I'm trying to create a multi-select element in HTML with 5 options

```
<select name="user" id="userName" multiple="multiple">
  <option>ALL</option>
  <option>ALL_2</option>
  <option>ABC</option>
  <option>XYZ</option>
  <option>PQR</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to have ALL and ALL_2 to be single selects. In that, what I mean is that if other options are selected along with ALL (or) ALL_2, then ALL (or) ALL_2 are to be deselected).

Ex: Selecting ALL/ALL_2 and then Ctrl + ABC, XYZ should be prevented (or) ALL should be deselected.

Selecting ABC,XYZ,PQR and then selecting ALL / ALL_2 should be prevented (or) ABC,XYZ,PQR should be deselected.

I'm looking to do this via MooTools/jQuery by looping through all options to select / deselect, but looking to see if there is a better way to do it since there could be a lot more than 5 options.

Summary : Options 3-5 are multi-selects but should not be used as multi-selects together with options 1 and 2. Apologies if this is confusing, tried to put my best to communicate it clearly.

Comment: Why don't you add `disabled` attribute to the option when either `ALL` or `ALL_2` is selected?

Comment: I thought of that but wouldn't that restrict the users from changing to a different option once ALL or ALL_2 is selected ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#user_name optgroup option').click(function () {
    // only affects options contained within the same optgroup
    // and doesn't include this
    $(this).siblings().prop('selected', false);
});
```

Something like this should work for you. Just group the `option`s to an `optgroup`. Here's a working [example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Rdgv/).

Comment: Thank you :) Something like this would get me started. This wouldn't exactly work because it sets the 'selected' value to 'False' only within the same optgroup but in my case, the communication should be within (AND) outside the optgroup. From your example : when OPT3 is selected and then OPT4 is selected, now OPT3 should be set to false.